# parachainSystem.OverlappingUpgrades

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, sudo, parachain-system

Attempt to upgrade validation function while existing upgrade pending

I stuck with this error.
Can anyone have idea how fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do this multiple times.

Sometimes, I make mistakes on my testnet (upload wrong WASM). Then I use sudo to kill the storage.

Kill the `ParachainSystem::PendingValidationCode` storage.

Comment: How to kill the storage?

Comment: Extrinsic -> system -> killstorage.

The default key is `0x45323df7cc47150b3930e2666b0aa31390d171f8401887cf06fb43a732994c32`.

If you modified your pallet name, then you should calculate the storage key youself.

Answer (score 1):

Xavier is right, and I'll show you how to kill it.

1. Get the storage key from chain state
   [image]
2. Then kill it by `system.killStorage` (sudo or governance)
   [image]